# How to hide a specific cell in google charts

Tags: google-visualization

We have something on a chart we want to hide we don't want to hide an entire column/row to hide this one cell and i can't seem to find any that answers my question so how do i hide a specific cell there is 21 charts going from 0-20
we are trying to hide number 3 and number 14 how do we remove/hide a cell?

Comment: i mean i did try to make it transparent but the line behind it disappears like it becomes non exsistent
and its a google org chart

Comment: you could use a data view to draw the chart, which has a method for [`hideRows`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataView_hideRows) -- you could exclude the row you want to hide before drawing